# Mongodb saves one day less - Time Zone Issue

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, date, mean-stack, timezone-offset

I post date in the format from angular as MM/DD/YYYY but but when it saves in Mongodb it saves the ISO() format with one day less. I am developing using MEAN stack.

eg :(from angular ) 10/03/2016 
     mongodb : ISODate("2016-10-02T18:30:00.000Z")

I would like to resolve the timezone issue while saving the date in mongodb .

Comment: what time zone is your client in ?

Comment: I want the timezone to be in the format of IST

Comment: The mongo db saves it is ISO format. You will have to change  to your time zone format while reading it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB saves date time in UTC. So, it changes from IST to UTC before saving. IST offset is +05:30 from UTC. So your date time 10/03/2016 00:00:00 goes back 2016-10-02T18:30:00.000Z, the same date time in UTC.

You have to set the time back to IST while fetching the data from MongoDb before presenting to the client.

Btw you should try and save the datetime in ISO format from the beginning.

More here on the MongoDB doc page for [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)

Comment: But If i have to save with the TIMEZONE of IST then how do I do it. Is there any possible way ?

Comment: no you cant and you should always save it in UTC and handle your conversion to user local zone in angular before presenting it to the user.